# Unexpected datetime format in Django

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a django project in which one of my models has a dateField named start_time. 
In my views.py I created a DetailView, and try to retrieve the timestamp like:

```
s = self.object.start_time.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
```

On my Raspberry Pi, it gives the expected result.

```
print(s)
22-Nov-2018
```

However on my Ubuntu 18 computer it gives:

```
print(s)
22-nov.-2018
```

How can I get my Ubuntu machine to give the same (expected) result as the Raspberry Pi?

They both run Django 2.1.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `%b` is locale-dependent (see the relevant [`strftime` doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)).

Check the locale on both machines; it's likely they're at least subtly different. Ensuring both are using the same locale would be ideal in any case, but particularly for dates, you might consider sticking to locale-independent numerical values instead.

Answer (score 0):

What finally fixed my problem was to, on the computer giving unexpected results, add

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

to `~/.bashrc`. 
Then open a new terminal or call `source ~/.bashrc`.

An alternative is to include

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8")
```

in `views.py` of the app.

You can check your current locale settings by calling `locale` from the terminal. In my case `LC_ALL` was blank.